# Can Visual Studio XAML designer handle font family names with spaces as a resource?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, fonts, xaml-designer

This probably seems like a strange question, but I'm having trouble seeing a custom true-type font that I've loaded as a resource in my WPF application, and I'm wondering if it may have to do with the space in the font name.

[As described elsewhere](http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx) (one of hundreds of examples), I've added the font to a folder `Fonts` in my application, and set it to `Build Action` = `Resource`. I'm able to reference the font (e.g., in a `TextBlock`) with a simple `FontFamily="Fonts\#My Font"`.

Unfortunately, the font only shows up at run time, not in the XAML designer (contrary to most people's problems). However, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615572/visual-studio-designer-isnt-displaying-embedded-font), this author had a similar problem with the font `Open Sans`, and if I install the font on my system, as he did, I can see it at design time.

But I'd rather not force developers to install the font on their system. I noticed that, like the author above, I don't have this problem with a few custom fonts that have names without spaces. So I'm wonder if this is perhaps a bug in Visual Studio (I'm using Community 2013). Has anyone been able to get this to work with a font whose name contains a space? Or has anyone found a more satisfying workaround (e.g., way to reference the font without the space akin to Windows short files names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this very same problem.  The solution is taking out the spaces, although you can't just edit the file name.  Here's how I did it:

- Download FontForge - http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/.
- Open the font file
- Go to Elements -> Font Info
- In there look for xyz Names, mine was TTF Names due to it being Wingdings
- Edit them to remove the spaces, I'm pretty sure the only one that matters is the "UniqueID" but I did them all.
- Go to File -> Generate Fonts and save the font as the proper type.
- Re-add the file and reference the font without spaces

This was the only way I could get it to work but it ended up working without a hitch.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! For the font I was using - PT Sans - I only had to edit the "PS Name"->"Family Name", as the "TTF Names" were attached (linked) to the PS (Postscript) Names. I chose to put underscores instead of spaces, which also worked. Grr to the Microsoft Visual Studio team. I tried to submit feedback but their bug reporting system appears to be down.